# Printing an immutable record (with Immutable object formatter extension enabled) prints nothing

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, immutable.js

I'm working on a javascript project using the immutable.js library.
To print any object coming from this library into the chrome console, I use the [Immutable object formatter extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/immutablejs-object-format/hgldghadipiblonfkkicmgcbbijnpeog) with the "enable custom formatters" option enabled in the console settings.

The said printed objects is not readable like shown on this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I tried reinstalling chrome, reinstalling the extension, turnoff every other extension nothing seems to work.
One thing to note is that when I change the position of the drawer it may display some data when the record is still collapsed in the console, but whenever I click it to get more details by expanding it, everything disappears and and looks like in the screenshot

Comment: I have seen this behavior in my own installation. IMO the addon is broken or does not play well with recent versions of Immutable.JS